# How to disable moving between workspaces feature?

Tags: linux-mint, workspaces, cinnamon

I have installed Linux Mint 14 Cinnamon – have been upgrading from Linux Mint 13.
There is a feature: 
 I can move between workspaces by moving cursor to the edge of screen and holding it there for about 1.5 seconds.

It is very useful, but sometimes annoying. And I cannot find where to turn off it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open Cinnamon Settings => Windows => Uncheck "Enable Edge Flip":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 17.1 and the Edge Flip choice has been moved to the 'Window Tiling and Edge Flip' section of system settings, under the Preferences category. It's a checkbox titled 'Enable Edge Flip'.