# How to disable mouse-over workspace switcher in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, workspaces

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57560/how-to-disable-moving-between-workspaces-feature) is the same question. But I can't find **Enable Edge Flip** option in System Settings => Windows menu to disabling this behavior in Mint 16.

Comment: Which version of cinnamon are you running? Please post the output of `cinnamon --version`. Also

Comment: Cinnamon 2.0.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now in `System Settings => Window Tiling and Edge Flip` which, really, should have been evident from the name:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help. In my localization it has been translated like "attraction to the borders" and confused me.

Comment: @Michael you're very welcome. Out of curiosity, what's your localization and how was it translated?

Comment: I'm from Russia and translate sounds like "Включить притяжение к границам".

Comment: In Mint 17.3, Not able to find the option called Window Tilling and Edge Filp instead I found Window Tiling in which not able to found Enable Edge Flip. Where can I found enable edge flip option.